# Vim language specific syntax validators?

Tags: vim

I've been using JSLint, I was wondering if there were any sort of syntax checkers I could use for ECMAScript/JS and possibly other languages so if I do something like :check or :syntaxcheck and it would point out the first or even multiple syntax errors ( which I hopefully don't have ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Running JSLint from your IDE](http://www.javascriptlint.com/docs/running_from_your_ide.htm) and

```
:help compiler
```

as well as [jslint.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2729).

Answer (score 3):

```
:help ft-vim-syntax
```

You can get it to 'point out' syntax errors by highlighting aggressively. Type the command above to read the docs.

Personally I just have

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

in my .vimrc, and 99% of the time I pick up syntax errors immediately because the colour isn't right :)

Answer (score 2):

This plugin is awesome:
http://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/tree

I don't know how it works standalone, but I highly recommend Scrooloose's vimfiles, which already includes the syntax checker. In ruby for example, it will mark the status line red and tell you in which line you have a syntax error and how many errors are in your source.